# How to use UNION clause result as table

Tags: php, mysql

```
propertyid  userid  shareddatetime
32          129     2015-02-03 11:09:33
33          129     2015-02-03 11:28:20
30          128     2015-02-03 11:33:02
32          128     2015-02-02 13:30:44
33          127     2015-02-02 13:40:44
30          128     2015-02-03 11:31:54
```

The above result is coming from the Query :

```
SELECT propertyid,userid,shareddatetime FROM `groupsharing` gs WHERE gs.groupid IN( SELECT `groupnum` FROM `groupuser` WHERE user = 129 ) AND gs.shareddatetime = (SELECT MIN(shareddatetime) FROM groupsharing gs2 WHERE gs.propertyid = gs2.propertyid )
     UNION 
    SELECT property,user,shareddatetime FROM sharing WHERE `shareduser` = '129' and `shareddatetime` = ( select min( `shareddatetime` ) from sharing s2 where s2.`shareduser` = sharing.`shareduser` and s2.`property` = sharing.`property` )
```

Now, How can I select the propertyid which has the minimum shared date time from the above result?

My expected result should be as following:

```
  propertyid  userid  shareddatetime
      32        128     2015-02-02 13:30:44
      33        127     2015-02-02 13:40:44
      30        128     2015-02-03 11:31:54
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Select a.propertyid, a.userid, min(a.shareddatetime) 
  from (SELECT propertyid,userid,shareddatetime 
           FROM `groupsharing` gs WHERE gs.groupid IN(SELECT `groupnum` FROM `groupuser` WHERE user = 129 ) AND gs.shareddatetime = (SELECT MIN(shareddatetime) FROM groupsharing gs2 WHERE gs.propertyid = gs2.propertyid )
        UNION 
        SELECT property,user,shareddatetime 
           FROM sharing WHERE `shareduser` = '129' and `shareddatetime` = ( select min( `shareddatetime` ) from sharing s2 where s2.`shareduser` = sharing.`shareduser` and s2.`property` = sharing.`property` )
        ) as a group by a.propertyid, a.userid;
```

Comment: Thanks brother, but it gives the following error:#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score -1):

the above answer is working as follow

SELECT propertyid, userid, shareddatetime FROM ( SELECT propertyid,userid,shareddatetime FROM `groupsharing` gs WHERE gs.groupid IN( SELECT `groupnum` FROM `groupuser` WHERE user = 129 ) AND gs.shareddatetime = (SELECT MIN(shareddatetime) FROM groupsharing gs2 WHERE gs.propertyid = gs2.propertyid ) UNION SELECT property,user,shareddatetime FROM sharing WHERE `shareduser` = '129' AND `shareddatetime` = ( SELECT min( `shareddatetime` ) FROM sharing s2 WHERE s2.`shareduser` = sharing.`shareduser` AND s2.`property` = sharing.`property` )) u
     WHERE u.`shareddatetime` = (SELECT MIN(shareddatetime) from (SELECT propertyid,userid,shareddatetime FROM `groupsharing` gs WHERE gs.groupid IN( SELECT `groupnum` FROM `groupuser` WHERE user = 129 ) AND gs.shareddatetime = (SELECT MIN(shareddatetime) FROM groupsharing gs2 WHERE gs.propertyid = gs2.propertyid ) UNION SELECT property,user,shareddatetime FROM sharing WHERE `shareduser` = '129' AND `shareddatetime` = ( SELECT min( `shareddatetime` ) FROM sharing s2 WHERE s2.`shareduser` = sharing.`shareduser` AND s2.`property` = sharing.`property` )) ui WHERE u.propertyid = ui.propertyid)